# Complete classification of topological spaces by compactness equivalences?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

In John Lee's *Introduction to Topological Manifolds*, the following theorems are proven:

- For all spaces:

  - Compactness $\Rightarrow$ limit point compactness
- For first countable Hausdorff spaces:

  - Limit point compactness $\Rightarrow$ sequential compactness
- For metric spaces and second countable Hausdorff spaces:

  - Compactness $\Leftrightarrow$ limit point compactness $\Leftrightarrow$ sequential compactness

**Can we strengthen this list so that, given a set of compactness equivalences, the topological properties of a space are precisely known?**

In other words, can we fill in the following blanks:

"Compactness $\Leftrightarrow$ limit point compactness" holds on (and only on) ___ spaces."

"Compactness $\Leftrightarrow$ sequential compactness" holds on (and only on) ___ spaces."

"Limit point compactness $\Leftrightarrow$ sequential compactness" holds on (and only on) ___ spaces."

Comment: Your question invites tautological fill-ins for each of those blanks. For example, "compactness $\iff$ limit point compactness" holds on (and only on) those spaces which are either (compact and limit point compact) or (not compact and not limit point compact).

Comment: I don't know a thorough answer, but if you pull up the wikipedia entry on "limit point compact", it says there that in $T_1$ spaces it is equivalent to countable compactness.

Comment: @LeeMosher That's true. I'm really hoping to fill in those blanks with familiar properties: first/second countability, separation axioms, and sequential properties (e.g., sequential space, Fréchet-Urysohn space, etc.).

Comment: In other words, is there an existing, standard classification scheme (or set of properties) that completely specifies which equivalences hold?

Comment: Possibly of use to you are Yao-Liang Yu's notes [*Various Notions of Compactness*](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~yaoliang/mynotes/compact.pdf) and a 1-page handout *Some Compactness Notions* I wrote for a class back in July 2003 (available if [you send me an email](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/13130/dave-l-renfro?tab=profile) with your email address).

Comment: Regarding countability properties, I'll guess that there are examples and counterexamples of each of these properties with arbitrarily "bad" countability properties (i.e. no basis of cardinality less than [insert favorite cardinal number here]).

Comment: limit point compactness in the strong sense? So every infinite subset has a point such that every neighbourhood of that point intersects the set in an infinite set? This is equivalent to "every infinite subset has a limit point" in $T_1$ spaces, but not always.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I'm not a huge fan of those notes so far because I've already spotted two errors: His Figure 1 suggests compactness is always equivalent to countable compactness, and also that first countability ensures limit point compactness is equivalent to sequential compactness.